# Paragraph formatting inside a css container

Tags: html, css

If I have a CSS container which I use for quotes, but the quote spans several paragraphs, how can I situate the formatting to show the multiple paragraphs inside the container? Example:

```
#quotebox {
width: 80%;
border-top: 1px solid #242729;
padding-left: 10%;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}
```

Is my container I use for quotes in my CSS. I then have a quote that's multiple paragraphs. Right now I have it like so:

```
<p id="quotebox">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... ”</p>
```

Where the quote is several paragraphs. If I do:

```
<p id="quotebox">

<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>

</p>
```

the formatting gets ruined. Is there a way to have multiple paragraphs show up under that kind of CSS container?

Comment: You can use `div` tag instead of `p` tag as wrapper.

Comment: Instead of a `div`, which is a reasonable suggestion, use `blockquote` for this, as it's semantically valid, and put the formatting on the `blockquote` element, with the paragraphs inside.

Comment: See [`blockquote` specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.2), e.g., *BLOCKQUOTE is for long quotations (block-level content)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p>` tags aren't allowed in `<p>`, so the browser is just splitting the markup into 4 `<p>` make `#quotebox` a div instead